Graph API online meetings - No application access policy found for this app
We are encountering application access policy issue when tried to access Online Meetings API.
We registered a new app registration and provided grants to application permissions for Online Meetings.

we followed MS documentation to configure access policy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy
we tried with different user accounts with both Global Administrator & Office 365 Admin Account but still we could not fix this issue.
As my user account is MFA enabled, I tried to logged in interactively in the browser.

My teams account is organizational one which resides in 1 tenant. The app registration that requires for online meetings created is in another tenant.
I already configured proper API permissions to app id "d070...". But still I am getting access denied.


This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1662180/no-application-access-policy-found-for-this-app. Please follow this thread for further updates.

Initially I got the same error as below:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/onlineMeetings/MeetingID


To resolve the error, check the below:
Created an application in TenantA and granted API permissions:

The user resides in the TenantB and when I tried to create the application policy, I got the same error:
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Ruk-policy -AppIds "TenantAAppID" -Description "Ruk"


For the user in TenantB, I assigned active Skype for Business Administrator role:

After assigning the role, re-connect to Microsoft Teams module with TenantB  user and create the policy and grant the policy:
Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Ruk-policy -AppIds "TenantAAppID" -Description "Ruk"

Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Ruk-policy -Global


Generate the access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


By using the above access token, I am able to query TenantB user meeting details successfully:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/onlineMeetings/MeetingID


To query TenantA (where the app resides) user online meeting details, connect to Microsoft Teams with TenantA user and create an application access policy and then query the user's meeting details.

We are able to reproduce a few steps in last week. we already gave permissions but we don't have Teams license in specific azure tenant which is blocking us. Have you checked this part? @rukmini

Yes to reproduce this you need to have teams license

That where we are struck and trying to get license :) Hopefully once we got license, we can grant application access policy.
